# jCarousel - cufon disappears after the first rotation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel, cufon

I'm using cufon with jCarousel.

The carousel has four items and they rotate from left to right.

The carousel is set to 'circular' and the cufon paragraphs are disappearing after the first rotation.

What can I do to get jCarousel and cufon to work so that the headlines don't disappear?

Answer (score 1):

How about trying something like this to refresh cufon on each 'rotation' - I'm assuming that your jCarousel container has a class of `jcarousel`:

```
$('.jcarousel').bind('jcarouselanimate', function(event, carousel) {
    Cufon.refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot and found that, Jcarousel does not include the jquery.jcarousel.js by default. So try adding the following line to the **jcarousel.module** file in modules/jcarousel.

```
 drupal_get_path('module', 'jcarousel') . '/js/jquery.jcarousel.js',
```

After that instead of this on line 287 of jquery.jcarousel.js...
    if (i + 1 < self.first) {

replace it to this...

```
if (i + 1 < self.first % this.options.size) {
```

All the best...

It worked for me.